# How do people get into 3W?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode "Dark Water," we hear of how when people died, they are brought to 3W.

3W stands for "3 Words", with the words being "don't cremate me." However, some of the people that end up in this facility *are* cremated. How can they show up there if they have been cremated? And how did the clockwork robot end up in 3W as well, considering the fact that he was a robot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In [Dark Water](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/34-11.html), the implication of cremation is pretty clear:

> SEB: Yeah. That last thing that happened to you, that really happened, I'm afraid. But that's life. Well, not life, I suppose, but. There are some forms to fill in. Might help you relax.
>
> Well, they won't, but we do need them filled in. Right, important thing. Need to know. Are you being cremated? Sorry, it's a fairly urgent question.
>
> DANNY: I don't know. I've never really thought of that.
>
> SEB: I'm going to put you down as a yes, that's pretty much the default these days. If people only knew.
>
> DANNY: Only knew what?
>
> (Seb rolls his chair back to the door and shouts through the wall.)
>
> SEB: We've got a burner in number twelve. Tell them to prep, please.
>
> DANNY: Burner?
>
> (Seb rolls back to the deck.)
>
> SEB: Yeah, it's fine, we'll come to that.

...

> (A man screams in agony nearby.)
>
> DANNY: What the hell is that?
>
> SEB: Sounds like somebody left their body to science. Okay. Er,  It's probably time to explain why you're always feeling cold.

...

> CHANG: What I'm about to play you will change your life and not for the better. These are the three words which caused Doctor Skarosa to set up institutes, like this one, all over the world, to protect the dead. If you'd rather not hear these words, there's still time
>
> DOCTOR: Can you just hurry up, please, or I'll hit you with my shoe.
>
> VOICE [OC]: Don't cremate me. Don't cremate me!
>
> CHANG: There is one simple, horrible possibility that has never occurred to anyone throughout human history.
>
> VOICE [OC]: Don't cremate me. Don't cremate me!
>
> CLARA: Don't say it.
>
> CHANG: The dead remain conscious. The dead are fully aware of everything that is happening to them.

The issue isn't that the cremated don't ascend, it's that their consciousnesses in Missy's matrix *experience* the agonizing destruction of their bodies.

As for the clockwork robot, it wouldn't be the first machine-based entity with a consciousness in Doctor Who. Apparently, a consciousness of any fashion will be collected in Missy's matrix, regardless of it's corporeal origins.

Comment: I had admittedly assumed that since the overhead would be hell, the whole 3 Words bit was just a giant scam to make sure Missy had more bodies to work with.  It's not like the billions of minds collected over centuries by her matrix would all have intact remains to return to - clockwork robot being a prime example.  But I forget, this is Doctor Who, and that this was actually done is just as likely.